Bundling javascript module issue
I'm very new to programming in javascript. I'm trying to bundle two modules via rollup. I'm trying to import a file - cars.js - into my index.js file.
Code for cars.js
const carsJSON = `[
    {
        "make": "Honda",
        "model": "Accord",
        "year": 1997,
        "price": 2800
    },
    {
        "make": "Toyota",
        "model": "Fortunner",
        "year": 2001,
        "price": 3500
    },
     {
        "make": "Hyundai",
        "model": "i20",
        "year": 2005,
        "price": 3000
    },
    {
        "make": "Maruti Suzuki",
        "model": "WagonR",
        "year": 1995,
        "price": 1200
    }
]`

export const cars = JSON.parse(carsJSON);

Here's the code for index.js
import { cars } from 'cars.js';

const message = cars[0].make;

And the code for bundle.js that was created
!function(s){"use strict";s.cars[0].make}(cars_js);
//# sourceMappingURL=bundle.js.map

But, when I'm loading the .html file on my local server I'm getting this error -
index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: cars_js is not defined
    at index.js:3:25

Here's the package.json that was created
{
  "name": "bundler",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "rollup -c",
    "watch": "rollup -c -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^26.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2"
  }
}

and the rollup.config.js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'build/bundle.js',
    format: 'iife', // Immediately Invoked Function Expression
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
    }),
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      preventAssignment: true,
    }),
    terser(),
  ],
};

Is there any issue with the bundling or how do I fix the error?

Where do you define cars_js?

Not related to the problem but why are you defining your data structure as JSON string first and then export const cars = JSON.parse(...) instead of just creating an object?

Your cars.js file should be exporting a default array of car objects.
export default [
  {
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Accord",
    year: 1997,
    price: 2800,
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Fortunner",
    year: 2001,
    price: 3500,
  },
  {
    make: "Hyundai",
    model: "i20",
    year: 2005,
    price: 3000,
  },
  {
    make: "Maruti Suzuki",
    model: "WagonR",
    year: 1995,
    price: 1200,
  },
];

And you should import is as:
import cars from './cars.js'; // Note the relative path

Make sure that cars.js is a sibling of your index.js file.

Update
In regards to this IIFE:
!function(s){"use strict";s.cars[0].make}(cars_js);

The loaded cars_js above is an array, since I changed it to a default export. It is trying to access a cars field on the scope, but it is an array now.
To fix this, you might need to change it back to a named export for it to work:
export const cars = [
  {
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Accord",
    year: 1997,
    price: 2800,
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Fortunner",
    year: 2001,
    price: 3500,
  },
  {
    make: "Hyundai",
    model: "i20",
    year: 2005,
    price: 3000,
  },
  {
    make: "Maruti Suzuki",
    model: "WagonR",
    year: 1995,
    price: 1200,
  },
];

Or:
const cars = [
  {
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Accord",
    year: 1997,
    price: 2800,
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Fortunner",
    year: 2001,
    price: 3500,
  },
  {
    make: "Hyundai",
    model: "i20",
    year: 2005,
    price: 3000,
  },
  {
    make: "Maruti Suzuki",
    model: "WagonR",
    year: 1995,
    price: 1200,
  },
];

export { cars };


the code works as in it doesn't show any error but the problem is, .html file should display a message about the 'make' for 0, which is Honda but nothing appears on the screen Am I missing something? I had mentioned in the index.js file const message = cars[0].make;

@proy added a follow-up section.

So, I tried both the methods but its creating an 'empty chunk' bundle.js. Is there a specific way I should import cars.js in my index.js file? I used import { cars }  from './cars.js'. from the second option (const cars)

@proy yeah, if it is not a default export, you destructure it during the import.
